# How do I pass an array of parameters to a Kendo Grid Datasource?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I would like to pass an array of data to a Kendo Grid Datasource.  The array will be a selection of Id's that return specific cars to the grid, I'm not sure how to do it.

Typically you can pass a single parameter to the grid by either directly declaring it inline or (the way I prefer) leverage `.Data` and specify a javascript function.

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetCars", "Grid").Data("myParams"))
```

You would then write a function to return your data, in this case a single Id, plus anything else you wanted from a record.

```
function myParams() {
    return {
        name: "Holden",
        id: 1
    }
}
```

Then we adjust the controller method to make use of the parameter.

```
public ActionResult GetCars([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int Id)
{
    var car = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get()Where(x => x.Id == Id);
    var result = car.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

That's all good and well for passing a single Id but I need to pass in an array of them.  I started down a path I thought would accomplish this but to be honest I'm not totally convinced.  I made a very crude initial approach in javascript, something like:

```
var cars = ["1", "2", "3"];

function myParams() {
    return {
        car: cars
    }
}
```

Then I adjusted my controller to accept the array like this:

```
public ActionResult GetTabVessels(string[] car, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    // Not sure how to handle it at this stage :(

    foreach (var item in car) {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    //Need to adjust this to accept the array.  Any ideas?
    var car = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get()Where(x => x.Id == Id);
    var result = car.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

After this point I realised I may need some guidance.  So, how do I pass an array of parameters (Id's in my case) to a Kendo Grid Datasource?

Many thanks

Comment: try "string[] car"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, returning the array is not the problem.  The problem is handling after it's at the controller and also knowing if it's even possible to pass an array to the DataSource

Comment: As I understand it now, do you want to return the array car to Kendo, is that correct? then just convert car to a list and call .ToDataSourceResult() and pass it to Json()

Comment: Thank you @Noren, You're exactly right.  Could you please help me implement that solution into my controller code above?  Just so I understand completely?

Comment: @Noren this post is about sending List (array) of Car to the javascript Kendo or #Yanayana you look for something else,

Comment: @Adrian yes, it's about sending an array to kendo and returning the results.  I bind using a repository pattern as you can see from my code and I want to pass the array in to return only the ID's specified.

Comment: I think  .Select(x=>x.ID) will work to only return ID. Please let me know by giving some example, It's still so confusing.

Comment: @Adrian Perhaps I have not explained my question well.  Basically, I want to pass in an array of integers which are Id's for remote bound date (sql database) and have Kendo return only those id's to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here is an untested example of how to return an array to Kendo:

```
public ActionResult GetTabVessels(string[] car, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    //ToList() is a Linq Extension
    return Json(car.ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: This is great, how would this incorporate with a repository datasource as above?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This example shows you how to pass an array to Kendo, as you asked...